# How can I add an image parameter in the WhatsApp API URL

Tags: image, api, url, parameters, whatsapp

Basically I want to send an image and some texts to WhatsApp from my website when the user clicks on the chat with WhatsApp icon

So I want to redirect users from my website to my WhatsApp chat!
I know we can add a text parameter to the WhatsApp API URL like this:

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=123456789&text=this is a test
```

But the fact is I want to add like an image parameter with the text parameter in the URL, for ex like this:

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=123456789&text=this is a test&img=[my-image]
```

Comment: You solved it because I am also looking for such an answer ?

Comment: Any one solve this problem

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score -2):

source_url but your text won't show (it's the text or the image)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).